# How to setup 2 environments for single project in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, pydev

I am working with a pydev project across 2 computers, one 32bit and another 64bit. When I switch between environments the libraries I need for my computer move from the Program files directory to the Programs (x86). These libraries are a third party and I do not have control over where they are placed.

If I add all the external libraries for both environments I get an error about the other libraries that are not available in the environment.

Has anyone else experienced this issue, is there a way to let eclipse know that this is not an issue?

Thanks

Comment: Can you specify a variable (like M2_HOME for Maven) to point to the libraries, and just change the variable when moving?  Or have a separate project for each architecture and just include the one fitting to the current machine.

Answer (score 1):

Well, easiest would be probably configuring multiple interpreters with each interpreter having that path correct in the first place, so, the actual project would have that already correct when use a given interpreter (note: virtualenv could be nice here).

If you want to make that a part of the project config, you could use variables for that (see below for generic example):

Let's say you want

/project/build/libs-32 (on 32 bits)

and

/project/build/libs-64 (on 64 bits)

So, you'd have to configure your project (right click project > properties > PyDev - PYTHONPATH > add based on variable)

/project/build/libs-${platform}

And then, in your interpreter configuration (window > preferences > pydev > interpreter - python > string substitution variables > set 'platform': '32' or '64' depending on your config)